# json object to html table conversion using json2html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am having a problem when using json2html https://github.com/eisenbraun/columns library . Is it possible to use this js library with Json object as below.

```js
var jsonobj = [{
  "id": "31",
  "Mesial": {
    "disorder": "",
    "other": ""
  },
  "Facial": {
    "disorder": "DC-HP",
    "other": ""
  },
  "Distal": {
    "disorder": "",
    "other": ""
  },
  "Lingual": {
    "disorder": "",
    "other": ""
  },
  "Occlusal": {
    "disorder": "",
    "other": ""
  }
}, {
  "id": "37",
  "Mesial": {
    "disorder": "",
    "other": ""
  },
  "Facial": {
    "disorder": "RE-AR",
    "other": ""
  },
  "Distal": {
    "disorder": "",
    "other": ""
  },
  "Lingual": {
    "disorder": "",
    "other": ""
  },
  "Occlusal": {
    "disorder": "",
    "other": ""
  }
}]
```

I have used online tool [Convert JSON to HTML Table](http://convertjson.com/json-to-html-table.htm), but unfortunately it's library is not available.

expected table output is

snap
[image]

Comment: You will  need to flatten that array to match what you want shown in each column. It's not clear what expected table should look like. You can use `Array#map()` to map it to the needed structure

Comment: Please update the code you tried. Please check this for documentation http://michaeleisenbraun.com/columns/

Comment: If you read the documentation you can see that the array needs to contain objects which define the columns, not further properties and subobjects: http://michaeleisenbraun.com/columns/

Comment: Will try to implement a method to flatten the json object. so it may work

Answer (score 2):

No, your data format is incorrect.

Your format need to respect their data format of :

```
[{"col1":"row1", "col2":"row1", "col3":"row1"}, {"col1":"row2", "col2":"row2", "col3":"row2"}]
```

Having for each object a `colX:rowY` format.

So you can't have an object as a row entry.

Comment: any suggestion to convert above json to flatten json?

Comment: @ArjunaBandara it depends on which values you want to keep in your actual json before converting it, but that's another question :)